# Uploading file doesn't work on second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to upload an excel file and send to api with reactjs, so far I can successfully send file to api. In my submit function, I also want to reset saved excel file from state when submitted, so I am doing as following

```
  const [urlImg, setURLImg] = useState("");
  const [excelFile, setExcelFile] = useState();

  function handleOnSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    setExcelFile();
    setURLImg("");
  }
```

But it is not working when I upload for the second time with the **same** excel file as previous one. I `console.log` the state but not showing anything, it seems like the whole component is not being rendered when submit with the same excel file. You can see my codesandbox sample [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-anything-dj1pc?file=/src/App.js:817-915)

[google drive link to download sample excel](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Ps_XecUyVcdx55VQIl9bNQdQY3FIzqkm?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the form's `onSubmit` event object to reset the file input field using the input's `id` property.

```
function handleOnSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  e.target["icon-button-file"].value = "";

  setExcelFile();
  setURLImg("");
}
```